# unable to run a mongoDb container in docker for windows using linux file system

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-for-windows

I am trying to run a mongo db container in windows with a volume mapping to a windows folder.

I have followed the answer by babak in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911021/unable-to-start-docker-mongo-image-on-windows) question. The folder maps properly, but it creates lots of files named WiredTiger.wt.1 where the number at the end keeps incrementing.

I get the following lines in the log:

```
2020-06-12T12:49:11.431+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.13233

2020-06-12T12:49:11.433+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1591966151:433603][1:0x7ff261e16b00], connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1591966151:433603][1:0x7ff261e16b00], connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted

2020-06-12T12:49:11.448+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1591966151:448092][1:0x7ff261e16b00], connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1591966151:448092][1:0x7ff261e16b00], connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists

2020-06-12T12:49:11.473+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.13234

2020-06-12T12:49:11.475+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1591966151:475038][1:0x7ff261e16b00], connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1591966151:475038][1:0x7ff261e16b00], connection: __posix_open_file, 667: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted

2020-06-12T12:49:11.477+0000 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.

2020-06-12T12:49:11.477+0000 F  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 1: Operation not permitted

2020-06-12T12:49:11.477+0000 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 915
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

As for me, such docker-compose.yml makes mongo start working:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
volumes:
  mongodata:
```

Comment: There should be another blank line after `mongodata:` else there seems to a error thrown by compose version 2.3